# Sphinx Mulit-Level Sort with Randomize

Tags: sphinx

Here is my challenge with Sphinx Sort where I have Vendors who pay for premium placement and those who don't:

I already do a multi-level order including the `PaidVendorStatus` which is either 0 or 1 as:

`order by PaidVendorStatus,Weight()`

So in essence I end up with multiple sort groups:

- PaidVendorStatus=1, Weight1
- ....
- PaidVendorStatus=1, WeightN
- PaidVendorStatus=0, Weight1
- ...
- PaidVendorStatus=0, WeightN

The problem is I have three goals:

1. Randomly prioritize each vendor in any given sort group
2. Have each vendor's 'odds' of being randomly assigned top position be equal regardless of how many records they have returned in the group (so if Vendor A has 50 results and VendorB has 2 results they still both have 50% odds of being randomly assigned any given spot)
3. Ideally, maintain the same results order in any given search (so that if the user searches again the same order will be displayed

I've tried various solutions:

`Select CRC32(Vendor) as RANDOM...Order by PaidVendorStatus,Weight(),RANDOM`

which solves `2` and `3` except due to the nature of `CRC32` ALWAYS puts the same vendor first (and second, third, etc.) so in essence does not solve the issue at all.

I tried making a `sphinx sql_attr_string` in my `Sphinx Configuration` which was a `concatenation` of Vendor and the record Title (`Select... concat(Vendor,Title) as RANDOMIZER`..)` and then used that to randomize

`Select CRC32(RANDOMIZER) as RANDOM...`

which solves `1` and `3` as now the `Title` field gets thrown in the randomization mis so that the same Vendor does not always get first billing. However, it fails at `2` since in essence I am only sorting by Title and thus Vendor B with two results now has a very low change of being sorted first.

In an ideal world naturally I could just order this way;

`Order by PaidVendorStatus,Weight(),RAND(Vendor)`

but that is not possible.

Any thoughts on this appreciated. I did btw check out as per `Barry Hunter`'s suggestion [this thread on UDF](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=10546) but unless I am not understanding it at all (possible) it does not seem to be the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one idea is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *,uniqueserial(vendor_id) AS sorter FROM index WHERE MATCH(...) 
       ORDER BY PaidVendorStatus DESC ,Weight() DESC LIMIT 1000
) ORDER BY sorter DESC, WEIGHT() DESC:
```

This exploits SPhixnes 'multiple sort' function with pysudeo subquery.

This works wors becasuse the inner query is sorted by PaidVendor first, so their items are fist. Which works to affect the ordr that unqique serial is called in.

Its NOT really 'randomising' the results as such, seems you jsut randomising them to mix up the vendors (so a single vendor doesnt domninate results. Uniqueserial works by 'spreading' the particular vendors results out - the results will tend to cycle through the vendors.

This is tricky as it exploits a relative undocumented sphinx feature - subqueries.

For the UDF see http://svn.geograph.org.uk/svn/modules/trunk/sphinx/

Comment: Thanks! Are you saying that that query with subquery will require implementing some UDF in my configs? Or it will work as you specified due to internal operations of Sphinx?

Comment: Yes, the UDF would need compiling and installing. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinx-udfs - the uniqueserial UDF is open source, and downloadable from the above url. Includes basic information on its use in the README

Answer (score 0):

Still dont have an answer for your biased random (as in 2.)

but just remembered another feature taht can help with 3. - can supply s specific seed to the random number. Typically random generators are seeded from the current time, which gives ever changing values, But using a specific seed.

Seed is however a number, so need a predictable, but changing number. Could CRC the query?

... sphinx doesnt support expressions in the OPTION so would have to caculate the hash in the app.

```
<?php

$query = $db->Quote($_GET['q']);
$crc = crc32($query);

$sql = "SELECT id,IDIV(WEIGHT(),100) as i,RAND() as r FROM index WHERE MATCH($query) 
             ORDER BY PaidVendorStatus DESC,i DESC,r ASC OPTION random_seed=$crc";
```

If wanted the results to only slowly evolve, add the current date, so each day is a new selection...

```
 $crc = crc32($query.date('Ymd'));
```

Comment: A lot to ponder thank you. All I really need the "static-randomness" to do is to maintain itself for a user's session. I just don't want them to search, then do the same search a second time a minute later and get entirely different results.  I'm sort of soft-focusing on this but if you are saying there is some time-based way to do this then if I did something based say per hour, are you saying I could sort of globally rotate through vendors each hour? As venfors grow I could just reduce the time interval (say every 10 minutes?)

Comment: I think I am going to cut my losses on this one. I "simply" used `reference` int field as a randomizer as per your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179958/crc32-on-integer-in-sphinx which allows me to get 1) and 3) of my original goals (randomize vendor, standardize results). Perhaps I'll look into a way to simulate RAND(Vendor) with the UDF but for now this gets me close enough. Is it worth doing a feature request for sphinx to push a value into RAND? This whole thing could be solved then by `order by Premium,Weight(),RAND(VendorID)` if that were possible

Comment: " Is it worth doing a feature request for sphinx to push a value into RAND? " - not sure. Dont think there is even a 'known' algoiruthm for biasing random number generator like that. Really its not a function of RAND as such, its a specific sort order you want.